# How to view ALL locations I have contributed to (photo, review...etc) in Google Maps?

Tags: google-maps

Only the locations around my country I have contributed to are pinned with a balloon. Is there a method to show all my contributions as pinned locations on Google Maps (i.e., all around the world)?